# Can one "cheat" refcheck to make unreferenced equations be as if they were referred to?

Tags: cross-referencing

My problem is the following. I have three equations

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
a=bc
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq2}
v=ut
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq3}
f=gh
\end{equation}
```

Later in the document, I refer to the three of them as `\eqref{eq1}--\eqref{eq3}`, thus the `refcheck` package tells me `eq2` has not been referred to. Is there any way to "make `refcheck` understand" that `eq2` has been referred to?

Comment: Have you tried cleverref? Then you would reference all three, but it would typeset as the range `\cref{eq1,eq2,eq3}` -> 'eqs. 1--3' or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `\eqref{eq2}` in a way that is not tyepeset, namely, in a temporary `\setbox`.  Here, I've made that into the macro `\phantomref{}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcheck,amsmath}
\newcommand\phantomref[1]{\setbox0=\hbox{\eqref{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{eq1}
a=bc
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq2}
v=ut
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq3}
f=gh
\end{equation}

In \eqref{eq1}--\eqref{eq3}\phantomref{eq2}, we see lots of variables.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks. Will accept the answer as soon as they let me.